# Electrum - Setting up a server - Problems!

Tags: client, electrum, sell-bitcoins

So im trying to request payment through my website but having problems.

Im using Windows 7 x32 as a testing environment. I installed Electrum via the installer and not the standalone exe.

First thing is that electrum is showing this in Preferences when it comes to SSL:

[image]

Im using a self-signed certificate that I generated from OpenSSL. Next, i think i messed up when it came to the rewrite settings because when I type in "electrum addrequest 3.14 -m "this is a test" " via CMD (with admin), two files  are generated in the right path of my server 
[image]

(the index.html was not generated, i coped it from one of the electrum folders)

the index.html was not generated, i coped it from one of the electrum foldersbut without the index.html. I actually tried finding a copy of the index.html and pasting it to the directy of the folder and tried doing the "index.html?id=(ID HERE)" but nothing changed as shown here!

[image]

When I tried doing "listrequests()" via the Electrum command line, i got this:

[image]

Can someone please tell me where I messed up?

Comment: Firstly, if you want to request payments through your website, it might not be necessary to use electrum. Maybe an easier solution might fit you. Secondly, this seems not very well documented, maybe you should try the electrum irc channel to find help on that...